# Compress variable css-selectors

Tags: css, variables, css-selectors

Is there any way to compress this css-selector?

```
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-address-und-0-name.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-address-und-1-name.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-address-und-2-name.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-address-und-3-name.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-address-und-4-name.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-address-und-5-name.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-address-und-6-name.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-address-und-7-name.form-text, {
    width: 493px;
}
```

I would save me a BUNCH of code!

**EDIT**
Here is the complete CSS I need to be compressed in as less code as possible:

```
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-0-naam.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-0-naam.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-1-naam.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-1-naam.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-2-naam.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-2-naam.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-3-naam.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-3-naam.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-4-naam.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-4-naam.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-5-naam.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-5-naam.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-6-naam.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-6-naam.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-7-naam.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-7-naam.form-text {
    width: 493px;
}

form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-0-straat.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-0-straat.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-1-straat.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-1-straat.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-2-straat.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-2-straat.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-3-straat.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-3-straat.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-4-straat.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-4-straat.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-5-straat.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-5-straat.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-6-straat.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-6-straat.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-7-straat.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-7-straat.form-text {
    width: 352px;
}
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-0-gemeente.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-0-gemeente.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-1-gemeente.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-1-gemeente.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-2-gemeente.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-2-gemeente.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-3-gemeente.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-3-gemeente.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-4-gemeente.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-4-gemeente.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-5-gemeente.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-5-gemeente.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-6-gemeente.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-6-gemeente.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-7-gemeente.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-7-gemeente.form-text {
    width: 362px;
}

form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-0-postcode.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-0-postcode.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-1-postcode.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-1-postcode.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-2-postcode.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-2-postcode.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-3-postcode.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-3-postcode.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-4-postcode.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-4-postcode.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-5-postcode.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-5-postcode.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-6-postcode.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-6-postcode.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-7-postcode.form-text,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input#edit-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-7-postcode.form-text {
    width: 100px;
}



form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-0-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-0-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-0-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-0-telefoon,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-1-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-1-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-1-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-1-telefoon,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-2-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-2-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-2-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-2-telefoon,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-3-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-3-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-3-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-3-telefoon,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-4-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-4-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-4-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-4-telefoon,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-5-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-5-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-5-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-5-telefoon,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-6-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-6-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-6-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-6-telefoon,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-7-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-7-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-7-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-7-telefoon,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-0-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-0-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-0-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-0-telefoon,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-1-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-1-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-1-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-1-telefoon,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-2-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-2-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-2-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-2-telefoon,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-3-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-3-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-3-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-3-telefoon,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-4-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-4-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-4-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-4-telefoon,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-5-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-5-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-5-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-5-telefoon,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-6-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-6-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-6-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-6-telefoon,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-7-straat,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-7-nr,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-7-postcode,
form#fiche-node-form.node-form div.form-item-field-bevoegde-adressen-und-7-telefoon {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: That's real pain to my eyes, may God assist you man! Only **evil** writes that code down

Comment: Just.. talk to front-end programmers to rearrange all equally visual `input` elements ones into the same class name selector, 'cause other way it'll be crazy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends entirely on your markup. First of all, if you're already using ID, you don't need to qualify that with an element name or a class name, since only one element may have that ID. So `form#finche-node-form` is the same thing as `#fince-node-form`, given that there will never be an element of that ID that is not a form.

`#finche-node-form.node-form` makes sense if you only want to apply the styles when the form has that class, and perhaps another style when it has another class. However, if your form will always have that class, or if you always want to apply that style to the form, regardless of whether it has that class, you can do with only `#finche-node-form`.

The rest of your code selects 8 different input fields. The same thing can be said about them. `#input#edit-field-address-und-6-name.form-text` can probably safely be reduced to `#edit-field-address-und-6-name`.

Now, the real space saver would be if you could find a way to target all 8 fields, without writing a separate selector for each, which is what you have here. That depends entirely on what your markup looks like. If these 8 fields happen to be your only input fields in the form, perhaps you can do with `#finche-node-form input`. Or else, if there are other elements, but only these 8 have the `form-text` class, then you could do with `#finche-node-form .form-text`.

If what you want to do is actually to apply this style to *all*  instances of `.form-text` then you could simply write

```
.form-text { width: 493px; }
```

So it all comes down to what your *actual* requirements are. There is not a single piece of that great long selector you've pasted that we can *know* to be safe to remove. There's a great deal we can *assume* will be safe, but only you can know what parts of the markup will be able to vary, and how you want your style to behave when it does.

Your selectors should express your intent. Your current selector makes the reader think that you want to target only a specific subset of elements, only within a specific form, and that the style should not always be applied but only in the perhaps rare condition where the form has a certain class, and the inputs have another certain class. If that actually is your intent, then perhaps the current selector isn't that bad. You should probably stop and think over things when your CSS selector makes the code more verbose than adding the style inline (although still easier to change, so hey).

If what you want to convey to the reader of your code (another developer or a browser) was really just "hey, I only want to make sure that all inputs in this form have this width", then that's what your selector should express.

**Update**

OK, now that we've seen your complete CSS code, we can verify that there are several different instances of `.form-text` that have different styles, so applying a single style to all elements of that class is obviously out of the question.

Some other questions:

- Is `#finch-node-form` ever anything other than a form? Otherwise you may remove the initial `form` part of the selector from every selector.
- Does it ever happen that `#finch-node-form` does *not* have the class `node-form`? If not, you may remove `.node-form` from all selectors.
- Are there any `<div>` elements in the form that should ever *not* have the float and margin? If not, you may reduce that entire last selector to `form#finche-node-form.node-form div` or perhaps `#finche-node-form div`.

  - If yes, is there anything else that is unique to the `div` fields where you do want to apply this style? For instance, if there are many `div`s, but the ones targeted in the above selector are *only* the ones that are immediate children of that form, and there are *no* other `div`s that are, you would be able to write `#finche-node-form > div { ... }`
- Is there anything that combines all 493px-textfields, and at the same time differentiates them from all 100px, 362px or 352px fields? Anything at all? If so, we may be able to target that `#finche-node-form > div:first-child > .form-text { ... }` (for instance).

Most important of all: **is editing the HTML out of the question?** Otherwise, you may simply introduce new classes, and apply your styles to them

```
#finche-node-form .width100-text-fields { width: 100px; }
```

(That's a terrible class name, but you get the idea)

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. Would you like me to post my entire CSS selectors?

Comment: Is that not all? Then I don't know if I dare say yes :D More than anything, I think it would be helpful if you *described* what you wanted to achieve. There's no single thing we can say will always be redundant.

Comment: @Mich: we still don't know the *intent* of your selectors, although we can now start to rule some simplifications out, such as `#finche-node-form .form-text`. But for all we know, after what you've posted now, `#finche-node-form div { float: left; margin-rigth: 20px; }` might still work. It would be useful, here, to find out what your markup looks like, and crucially, *whether it is an option to alter your markup*

Comment: Altering my markup is only possible after using a hook (it's a Drupal website). I can alter the HTML, but I prefer not to (cause it's not that easy)

Comment: @Mich: as I've said, there's no single piece of your selectors that are *inherently and in all scenarios ever imaginable* redundant. There may still be heaps of your selectors that are redundant in your specific scenario. *We* can never know that from purely looking at your CSS. See my updated answer. It has a handful of suggestions on what *might* be possible to do, but it all depends on circumstances that only you can know. To go more in depth, we'd have to see the markup, and not just the styles.

Comment: thanks for your time and effort in explaining this matter! I think it will be best to change my HTML (although, it won't be easy). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [attribute starts with selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors):

```
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input[id^="edit-field-address-und"].form-text {
    width: 493px;
}
```

I'm assuming that you don't have any other elements that also have an ID starting with `edit-field-address-und`.

Comment: I'm afraid so... The page is filled with `edit-field-address-und-...` links. Always followed by a number and specific term (name, street, number, zip,...)

Comment: It's hard to recommend exactly what to do without seeing your entire HTML/CSS. To be honest, it sounds like you haven't thought this out optimally. The most likely answer is that you need to add a second class to each of these `input`s and set the `width` on that.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't be a good approach for Internet Explorer users

Comment: @thirtydot No man, see the link you posted, it's CSS3. This selectors are buggy for IE7+ (not to mention ie6)

Comment: @Nacho: see the comment on IE7 on that same link, though. It describes exactly what the bugs are, and I don't immediately recognize that any of those bugs would mean that the above selector cannot be used.

Comment: @Nacho: Read the link I posted carefully. Yes, it's buggy, but it works provided that you bear in mind the bugs. [My specific usage of `^=` works flawlessly in IE7.](http://jsfiddle.net/y57cJ/) Nobody gives a shit about IE6.

Comment: @Nacho: Just because it's CSS3 doesn't mean IE7 sucks at supporting it. It does a wonderful job of supporting quite a number of CSS3 selectors and properties, and even beats some modern browsers in that aspect (considering it came out in 2006...). And buggy support does not mean no support. You just run into problems in certain cases, but that shouldn't stop you from using it altogether.

Comment: @BoltClock I know, I agree with you, and I was going to agree with thirtydo, but i still do give a shit about IE6... 3% of internet users still do.

Comment: Well... I am the 97%. #occupyIE

Comment: If it where that easy... that 3% still want to use the site and won't follow the tag. (I do follow it)

Answer (score 1):

Using a CSS pre-processor, such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/):

```
form#fiche-node-form.node-form input {
    &#edit-field-address-und-1-name,
    &#edit-field-address-und-2-name,
    &#edit-field-address-und-3-name,
    &#edit-field-address-und-4-name,
    &#edit-field-address-und-5-name,
    &#edit-field-address-und-6-name,
    &#edit-field-address-und-7-name {
        &.form-text { width: 493px; }
    }
}
```